# Reports against a single SQL Table

Tags: sql, report

I'm looking for a freeware program that is pretty much BusinessObjects.

We have 1 SQL table which has loads of data in it that users constantly want reports from. Everytime they ask it's an ad hoc query written just for the moment.

It would be much nicer to be able to give users a solution to create there own reports.  Kind of like BusinessObjects :),  but free and easy to use ofc :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on SQL Server, check out [PebbleReports](http://www.pebblereports.com/) - free (at least now) and you can just ask for a license key.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try [JasperReports](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=jasperreports) and its GUI, [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/project/project_home.php?projectname=ireport).